# Setting Alternative Session Expiration Times in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, variables, timeout

I want a specific session variable (in my case Session["level"]) to expire either on the normal 20 min. timer or at 19:30 every day. Because I change a value in my database everyday at 19:30 and I want this session variable to be related to that value. Is this possible? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
    if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > TimeSpan.Parse("19:30"))
    {
        Session["level"] = null;
    }
```

If you're using masterpages or all of your aspx pags are extending a base page, put it inside the page_load.

You could also stick code in the method to grab the updated Session["level"] value and assign it, instead of setting it to null.

Comment: Well, this solution would always set session null when after 19:30. What I want is to reset session if it existed before 19:30. Anyway as a solution I used this: use another session value that keeps the time session was set and after 19:30 check if that time is under 19:30, if so reset session["level"].

Comment: Oh, well your question makes it seem that regardless you'd want to the Session variable to reset at 19:30....since that's when you change the value.  Glad you worked it out! :)